# Replace '\' with '-' in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, html-escape-characters

I have seen all the questions asked previously but it didn't help me out . I have a string that contains backslash and i want to replace the backslashes with '-'

```
var s="adbc\sjhf\fkjfh\af";
s = s.replace(/\\/g,'-');
alert(s);
```

I thought this is the proper way to do it and of course i am wrong because in alert it shows `adbcsjhffkjfhaf` but i need it to be like `adbc-sjhf-fkjfh-af`.

What mistake i do here and what is the reason for it and how to achieve this...??

[Working JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GHBV8/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `s` is initially `adbcsjhffkjfhaf`. You meant

```
var s="adbc\\sjhf\\fkjfh\\af";
```

Comment: when i use that string for some operations it takes it as 'adbcsjhffkjfhaf' or 'adbc\sjhf\fkjfh\af'

Comment: It does have an invisible form feed (`\f`) and a bell (`\a`), but no backslashes. What operations are you talking about?

Comment: Operations like creating JSON using that string

Comment: JSON encoder escapes the form feed and the bell again to present them using printable characters. There should be no `\s` in the JSON string.

Answer (score 3):

You need to double-up the backslashes in your input string:

```
var s="adbc\\sjhf\\fkjfh\\af";
```

Prefixing a character with '\' in a string literal gives special meaning to that character (eg `'\t'` means a tab character). If you want to actually include a '\' in your string you must escape it with a second backslash: `'\\'`

Comment: when i use that string for some operations it takes it as 'adbcsjhffkjfhaf' or 'adbc\sjhf\fkjfh\af' .. ?

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is ignoring the `\` in `\s` `\f` `\a` in your string. Do a `console.log(s)` after assigning, you will understand.

You need to escape `\` with `\\`. Like: `"adbc\\sjhf\\fkjfh\\af"`

Comment: when i use that string for some operations it takes it as 'adbcsjhffkjfhaf' or 'adbc\sjhf\fkjfh\af'..??

Answer (score 1):

The string doesn't contain a backslash, it contains the \a, \s and \f (escape sequence for Form Feed).

if you change your string to `adbc\\sjhf\\fkjfh\\af`

```
var s="adbc\\sjhf\\fkjfh\\af";
s = s.replace(/\\/g,'-');
alert(s);
```

you will be able to replace it with `-`